# Google MyBusiness PHP Api OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL

Tags: php, google-my-business-api

Part of my code is:

```
try {

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig($credentials_file);

    $client->setAccessType("offline");
    $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
    $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage");
}catch(GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException $e){
    Connector::handleException($e); //just print $e->getMessage(); and die();
}catch(\Exception $e){
    Connector::handleException($e); //just print $e->getMessage(); and die();
}

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {

    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
    $connector = Connector::init($client);

    require_once "views/index.php";

} else {
    $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php';
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

in `views/index.php` i just get locations and print them out.

i run my 'app' with `php -S localhost:8000`

Almost everything is ok, because some time to time ive got error:

`cURL error 35: OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to mybusiness.googleapis.com:443 (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)`

and

`cURL error 35: OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to oauth2.googleapis.com:443 (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)`

I need refresh site couple times till everything back to normal. Few days ago everything was fine. Sometimes it start working after first refresh, sometimes it take 5 minutes.

Why? Can I somehow fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Google API have problems with curl with IPv6, so in file:

`vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlHandler.php`

about line 40 I've added:

`curl_setopt($easy->handle, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);`

and it resolved problem!